# XCODE 14 BETA, DONT SEND TO REVIEW

Tags: xcode

After upgrading to OS ventura, I followed the team's advice and installed Xcode 14 beta to continue using it, but when uploading the app to the connect store, it was not possible to send for analysis applications that were sent by xcode beta, what should I do now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only push builds to App Store Connect from a stable version of Xcode. Xcode 13 (the latest stable version) does not run on macOS Ventura so you will need to either revert to macOS Monterey or, if you're working in a team, ask a team member with macOS Monterey to upload the build instead.

If you have a backup (as you should), I suggest reverting to macOS Monterey and installing macOS Ventura [on a separate partition](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208891) as detailed by Apple.

Comment: It should also be possible to install macOS Monterey in a VM under Ventura.